# Schedule plugin not working for Feed Me plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, plugin-feedme, cron, api

I have created a schedule to run the '[Feed Me](https://plugins.craftcms.com/feed-me)' every 1 minute using the plugin '[Schedule](https://plugins.craftcms.com/schedule)', but it doesn't work. I not sure am I using the correct setting or not. I manage to get the latest data if I manually click the 'Run Feed'.

This is my setting for 'Schedule'
[image: This is my settings]

This is my timer
[image: This is my timer]

Comment: Hi @Lee, I take it you've set up the cron job?

Comment: @dmatthams You mean this step 4 '* * * * * php /path/to/craft schedules/run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1' ? I don't have idea what is the refer to. I keep getting the error 'The system cannot find the path specified'. I'm using windows.

Comment: The path is the path to where you installed craft on your server – your host might be able to help with this?

Comment: I tried to run at my localhost using XAMPP. I think the command line is different? If I run with craft schedules/run, I can see the full list of the job. This line ' 1>> /dev/null 2>&1' doesn't work at Window.

Comment: This isn't normally something you'd run on a local environment. You'd set it up on your sever to repeat a task, most web hosts will have guides on how to setup a cron job.

Comment: @dmatthams Thanks for your reply. If like this, then I will work at the server straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you didn't do step #4 in the readme? https://github.com/panlatent/schedule/blob/master/README.md

> 4. Add a record to system crontab:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/craft schedules/run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: What is the /path/to/ ? I'm new to this cron job, not sure what is the path/to refer to. I had tried for a few, but it return 'The system cannot find the path specified'.  I'm using a window.

Comment: That's the full path to the `craft` executable at the root of your project.